# Checking content of many small files in PHP

Tags: php

I have an unusual problem. Using PHP script, I have to traverse through a folder with around 1 million small text files (size ranges from 1KB to 1MB), and pick only those with `ctime` in certain interval AND content containing particular search string.

First part (picking files that have time of creation in certain range) I managed using `readdir` but checking the file content for search string proves to be a challenge. Using `file_get_contents` (and then `stripos`) simply won't do. It's slow, it brings my PHP script to its knees.

I'm sure I'm not the first one with this kind of a problem, but I'm not a PHP developer. This code has been inherited from previous dev. I'm not sure which alternative I should be using and what code would spare my server RAM and CPU.

Comment: Is the "PHP script" a web-based script? Perhaps you could do your checking task with a script outside of a web context, where it does not need to be fast. Do you need to do this search once, or on an ongoing basis? If the latter, how often would you wish to refresh your search?

Comment: Did you try to read in batches?

`// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character
$section = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FALSE, NULL, 20, 14);`

[check](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: @mustafa96m, no, i haven't but it seems interesting! So i read content bit by bit until i find the character?

Comment: @halfer it's a script used by few select users to check some log files on a daily basis using a web browser. So, it's used often

Comment: sounds like you need something like Splunk

Comment: I would say chunk by chunk and fetch in smaller batches is always faster then processing huge batch at once.

Comment: @mustafa96m but if i do that in a loop, how can i make sure no RAM is taken when i confirm file contains wanted string and do "break". This isn't an OO-PHP script :\

Comment: @dmikester1 hmmm sorry, never heard of it :\

Comment: @guest86: that does not really answer my question, would you be more specific? If your users need to see the result of this very slow search, does it matter if the results are 10 minutes out of date? 30 minutes? I suspect an offline process could load and inspect these files in 10 minutes or so, and thus you could just show users the results of the last full offline scan.

Comment: @mustafa96m: that sounds slower than just loading files into RAM, assuming the whole of each file needs to be searched.

Comment: @halfer ah, no, at first occurrence of the string i just need to note the position and that's it! Also, 10 minutes is way to long, i got complaints when searching process took more than a minute :) And files get generated in random intervals so it's important to search through file as soon as it's available.

Comment: @guest86: I think you misunderstand my question. I was proposing that a search is done offline, and the results aggregated for users (slow search operations based on preset searches, fast result display in the web). However, now that you indicate that your users need to do live searches, that may be a different matter. If that is really the case, then you simply cannot search the files - it is too slow. You will need a search index, such as Elasticsearch or Lucene. The only problem is that you will need to continually feed the index, so the results will always lag behind.

Answer (score 3):

I would try `shell_exec` combined with `find` and `grep`:

```
$output = shell_exec("find . -type f -ctime $MyCtime -exec grep -H -m 1 $MySearchString {} +;");
```

`-H` to show filename

`-m 1` to stop searching at first ocurrence in file

Answer (score 2):

PHP won't handle it easily(it will take lots of time + will overload the CPU), consider to use bash and regular expressions to solve the problem

Simply saying, PHP is not the right tool in the situation